# proper way to reterive last item from json array, stored in file

Tags: python, json

Below is how my JSON file looks like, Here I am continuously watching this. I am watching this file because I want to retrieve the every new item appended to JSON array in Python.

I want to know what could be a better approach.

```
[
  {key1:value1,key2:value2},
  {key1:value1,key2:value2}
]
```

Comment: Explain better your question, because as it's presented a simple `json.load(file)` and a list manipulation do the work.

Comment: I want to know best practice for such tasks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that way could be a good one:

```
import json

# path to the JSON file
json_file_path = 'your_file.json'

# Read the JSON content from the file
with open(json_file_path, 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)

# Check the data received is a list
if isinstance(data, list):
    # Check that it's not empty
    if data:
        # Get last item
        last_item = data[-1]
        print(last_item)
    else:
        print("The JSON array is empty.")
else:
    print("The JSON data is not in the expected format (list of dictionaries).")
```